# How to avoid glob expansion when running a Java app in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, wildcard, expansion

I am running into a peculiar behavior of the Eclipse run configuration, and it appears to be a Windows-only problem. Suppose I have a Java app that prints out the command line arguments, like the following:

```java
public class WildCard {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String arg: args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

If I provide argument with a wild card that can be expanded by the shell, the shell will expand it and give it to the Java program. That's no surprise. So, if I do on the command prompt

```
java WildCard test/*
```

the program will print

```
test/foo.txt
test/bar.txt
```

where foo.txt and bar.txt are files in the directory "test".

Shell expansions can be prevented if I surround the wildcard argument in quotes; single quotes on *nix, and double quotes on Windows. So for Windows, if I do the following on the command prompt:

```
java WildCard "test/*"
```

the program will now print

```
test/*
```

(no expansion).

However, what I find is that the quoting in the Eclipse run launcher seems to have no effect, and the argument is still expanded. If I put

```
"test/*"
```

in the program argument section in the Eclipse run launcher, and run the above class, I still get

```
test/foo.txt
test/bar.txt
```

In other words, the double quotes seem to be lost when the program actually runs. This seems to happen only with Windows.

Is there a way to prevent the glob expansion with the Eclipse run launcher on Windows?

Comment: I am inclined to believe this is a bug with eclipse, but wanted to see if there is a viable workaround to the problem.

Comment: My suggestion of escaping the wildcard with backslashes does not really work. It **does** work in the test case I used (and I still don't know why) but not in other cases. I am deleting my answer since it is not actually solving the problem.

Comment: I found an existing eclipse bug on this... http://goo.gl/eM6e

Comment: I'm wondering where does the launcher 'java' process the wildcard expanding. I could not find it in the source code of jdk.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, but I found this article helpful, http://mindprod.com/jgloss/wildcard.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks quite wired:

```
*.txt
foo.*
```

will NOT be expanded, but

```
*
*.*
"*"
"*.*"
\"*\"
\"*.*\"
```

will be expanded.

It looks like only "all files" is expanded, but all other strings (including *) will stay unchanged.

I'm at the same problem and I use XP and eclipse 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `(.*)` will not be expanded by eclipse, and still works as a regex.