# Wildcard Expansion in Eclipse Run Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, wildcard, glob

Is there a way to make Eclipse expand wildcards in run configuration arguments?  My class can handle the command line arguments passed to `main(String[] args)`.  From a normal shell (bash on my system), it is simple:

```
$java MyClass file*.txt
```

This runs my class with all files in the working directory that start with `file` and end in `.txt` supplied as command line args.

I would like to have this same behavior inside eclipse, but when I enter `file*.txt` into the run configuration editor and run the program, the wildcard is not expanded.  Rather than a list of files, the only arg recognized is the literal string `file*.txt`.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861086/how-to-avoid-shell-expansion-when-running-java-app-in-eclipse) leads me to believe that it is possible or was once possible (at least on Windows - I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.8), but those folks were having the opposite problem of wildcards being expanded even when that behavior was not wanted.

In trying to solve this problem, I have tried using different environmental variables (i.e., ${string_prompt}, changed the working directory, looked through the Eclipse preferences and documentation, and googled relevant phrases but nothing has worked.  Any suggestions or links to relevant information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you say, I want to know where and who does the expanding, and I want to control it.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be the desired behavior in Eclipse. Indeed, wildcard expansion in Windows is considered as [a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=212264).

In contrast, the desired behavior in bash is what you expect, but Java (and hence your program) has no knowledge about it.

If you want your program to be *smart* and expand wildcards, you could use [`WildcardFileFilter`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/WildcardFileFilter.html) which is part of [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library.

Even better: you could write an Eclipse plugin that supports command line expansion. If you do so, please share! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the information Eric. I will definitely look into `WildcardFileFilter`. I don't have much (read _any_) experience writing Eclipse plugins, but I'll do some research to see if it is something I think I can handle. Thanks again.