# Passing the asterisk as command line argument to main in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a Java project in Eclipse and now I'd like to pass the asterisk `*` as a command line argument to the main. I'm aware of the fact that this is a wildcard symbol and in every shell it works fine by simply putting it into quotes, so instead of `java MyProgram *` I'd type `java MyProgram "*"`.

In Eclipse (Run Cofigurations -> Arguments) it doesn't work either way, even with quotes it just lists all files inside the directory. Single quotes as in `'*'` works the same way as `a*a` or something, meaning the single quotes (or apostrophes) will be passed into the string, too.

Any ideas how to get the `*` into the main?

Comment: Did you try escaping it with a backslash?

Comment: Yes, which results in listing all files and folders from my root directory (in my case "C:\"). Oh, I should add that I'm working on windows ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861086/how-to-avoid-shell-expansion-when-running-java-app-in-eclipse , and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=212264

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse expands the * into a list of property names.  So the program is actually passed (on my system) an args array of:
.classpath, .project, .settings, .bin, .src
Instead of the * .

If I put ANY text with the *, like "X*", then I get the "X*".

Doubles quotes does not help.  Neither does escaping it with a slash.

From the shell it works fine, although a warning on Windows at least that you do need to put it in quotes.  Windows will strip the quotes before the program gets it.

But under Eclipse, I can find no workaround that allows passing just a * .

Answer (score 0):

To anyone running into the same problem, you need to write it as "* " for eclipse to pass it as *

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Select Run Configurations from Run dropdown menu.

Go to Arguments tab.

Tick the @argfile box.

Answer (score -2):

It's a programming bug in your own program. Eclipse passes the main arguments verbatim to your program. You can easily check this by creating a Java program which has only this one line in main:

```
System.out.println(args[0]);
```

and passing an asterisk as the only argument to that program in the run configuration. That prints the single asterisk character, as expected.

Comment: `package asterisk;

public class CmdLineArgAsteriskTest
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  System.out.println(args[0]);
 }
}`

is now my main program and the output is:

`.classpath`

Comment: I've tried mine before posting. I've created a new Java project, containing that line of code, a new run configuration of type "Java application" and I've put "*" in the program arguments field of the run config. Your project or run configuration seems to be different at some place. I'd suggest you create an entirely new project and run configuration for verification.

Comment: @Bananeweizen I get .classpath also.  Clear eclipse does something with *